# I am still confused with the count operation of the exponentiation operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

how does the workflow of one operator precedence ie exponentiation I am still confused by the way there work can explain how it works?

Comment: Can you give us an example you're confused about?

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I am confused with the operation of 2 ** 3 why its 8 results

Comment: Are you asking about the mathematical operation itself or the precedence of the operator? 2**3 is 2 to the power of 3, or 2*2*2, or 8.

Comment: "_2 ** 3 why its 8 results_" Because 2 * 2 * 2 = 8.

Comment: Why wouldn't `2**3` be 8? That's how exponents work.

Comment: @csmckelvey so is this like a sophisticated math operation?

Comment: Just normal exponents - "2 to the power 3". Sometimes written as `2^3`. `2 ** 3` is just another way of writing it.

Comment: @Hafizd do you consider exponents "sophisticated"?

Comment: Take a look at how this ES6 feature is explained over at The Exponentiation Operator in JavaScript. It seems to be a pretty good write-up about how it works. https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/24/the-exponentiation-operator-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the result of `2 ** 3` is 8 because

```
2 * 2 * 2  === 8
```

i.e. 2 multiplied by itself three times is 8.

Likewise `2 ** 8` is 256 because

```
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 === 256
```

The operator is however somewhat "strange" because it is right-associative while all others math operations are left associative:

```
x / y / z  ===  (x / y) / z
x - y - z  ===  (x - y) - z

// but

x ** y ** z  ===  x ** (y ** z)
```

and also the `**` operator plays strangely with unary operators...

```
-2**8       // syntax error
(-2)**8     // ok, value is 256
-(2 ** 8)   // ok, value is -256
```

Note also that while the explanation of `x ** y` as "x multiplied by itself y times" makes sense for non-negative integer values of `y`, the exponentiation operator is more general and for example `x ** 0.5` is the same as `Math.sqrt(x)`.